# Simulate multinomial logistic regression model

Tags: simulation, multinomial-distribution, computational-statistics

I want to simulate multinomial logistic regression model i have 3 independent continuous variable. I need to simulate a dependent variable which have 5 levels with suitable beta coefficients. Please can anyone help me?